# How to get the type that a DependencyProperty uses for its value in Silverlight?

Tags: c#, silverlight, dependency-properties

I want to check what the type of a DependencyProperty is and in WPF I could do the following:

```
DependencyProperty property = ...;
var typeAsString = property.PropertyType.Name;
```

As the `PropertyType` is [only available](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.dependencyproperty.propertytype(v=vs.110).aspx) in WPF.

I am wondering if there is another way of achieving this in Silverlight.

Answer (score 0):

I think this might be worth a look for you.
[How to get a DependencyProperty by name in Silverlight?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2220474/how-to-get-a-dependencyproperty-by-name-in-silverlight)

You have to use reflection:

```
     public static DependencyProperty GetDependencyProperty(Type type, string name)
 {
     FieldInfo fieldInfo = type.GetField(name, BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Static);
     return (fieldInfo != null) ? (DependencyProperty)fieldInfo.GetValue(null) : null;
 }
```

as seen in the answer the usage is:

```
 var dp = GetDependencyProperty(typeof(TextBox), "TextProperty");
```

HTH

Comment: Thanks for the reply, unfortunately I have seen this and it works as expected but not for what I am trying to achieve. It will give me the DP from a string, what I want is find what is the type that the DP represents so that I can create a "parser" to set a value to it that comes from a persistence implementation.